# WebRTC - how to switch between getUserMedia and getDisplayMedia tracks inside RTCPeerConnection

Tags: stream, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm trying to develop an app where users can can video call to each other and share their screens using WebRTC technology. I have succeed with either video call or screen sharing app and now I'm trying to make it to be able to switch between getUserMedia and getDisplayMedia on button click during a call inside the same RTCPeerConnection but it doesn't work.

This is how I thought it could work:

```
            function onLogin(success) { 

                var configuration = { offerToReceiveAudio: true, offerToReceiveVideo: true, "iceServers" : [ { "url" : "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302" } ] }; 

                myConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection ? new RTCPeerConnection(configuration, { optional: [] }) : new RTCPeerConnection(configuration, { optional: [] }); 

                myConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) { 
                    console.log("onicecandidate");
                    if (event.candidate) send({ type: "candidate", candidate: event.candidate });
                };
                
                myConnection.ontrack=function(e){
                    try{remoteVideo.src = window.webkitURL?window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(e.streams[0]):window.URL.createObjectURL(e.streams[0])}
                    catch(err){remoteVideo.srcObject=e.streams[0]}
                }
                
                myConnection.ondatachannel=openDataChannel
                openDataChannel();
                
                startAVStream();
                //startSStream()
            };

            function startAVStream(enable){
                if(sStream)sStream.getTracks().forEach( function (track) {
                            try{myConnection.removeTrack( track, sStream );}
                            catch(e){}
                        } );
                        
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then(s => {
                    if(!avStream){
                        avStream = s;
                        avStream.getTracks().forEach( function (track) {
                            myConnection.addTrack( track, avStream );
                        } );
                    }
                }, function (error) { console.log(error); }); 
            }
            
            function startSStream(enable){
                if(avStream)avStream.getTracks().forEach( function (track) {
                            try{myConnection.removeTrack( track, avStream );}
                            catch(e){}
                        } );
                        
                navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true }).then(s => {
                    if(!sStream){
                        sStream = s;
                        sStream.getTracks().forEach( function (track) {
                            myConnection.addTrack( track, sStream );
                        } );
                    }
                }, function (error) { console.log(error); }); 
            }
```

Can anyone tell me how I can switch between tracks inside the same RTCPeerConnection or should I create 2 separate RTCPeerConnection - one for video/audio streaming and another for screen sharing?

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `RTCRtpSender.replaceTrack` to splice the screen capture track.  This doesn't require renegotiation, and therefore has very low latency.

```
let newstream = navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({});
let newtrack = newstream.getTracks()[1];
if(newtrack.kind !== 'video')
    throw new Error('Eek!?');
pc.getSenders().forEach(async s => {
    if(s.track && s.track.kind === 'video')
        await s.replaceTrack(newtrack);
});
```

The test for `s.track` not being `null` deals with the case where you previously called `replaceTrack(..., null)`.

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks a lot! But now I have another question - ejat do I do when I use only audio stream? Coz it gives me an error when I try to add getDisplayMedia stream.

Comment: Just replace both occurrences of `video` with `audio`.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean:(

Comment: Which stream is an audio-only stream?  If you want to replace the audio track, do the same as above but with 'audio' instead of 'video'.  If you want to add a video track to an audio-only stream, you'll need to call `addTrack` on the pc, which requires renegotiation.

Comment: hello, this works for me on chrome. but my remote stream stuck when I stopped the screen sharing from the chrome screen sharing button. any idea please?

Comment: Just add an `onended` callback to the track that reverts to the previous situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 shareScreen = () =>{
const success = (stream) => {
  window.localStream = stream
  // this.localVideoref.current.srcObject = stream
  // localStream.replaceStream(stream);
  this.setState({
    localStream: stream
  })

  Object.values(this.state.peerConnections).forEach(pc => {
    pc.getSenders().forEach(async s => {
      console.log("s.track ",s.track);
      if(s.track && s.track.kind === 'video'){
        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
          // pc.addTrack(track, this.state.localStream)
          s.replaceTrack(track);   
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
const failure = (e) => {
  console.log('getUserMedia Error: ', e)
}
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ cursor: true }).then(success).catch(failure)}
```